# multi-line parsing of the configuration file with comments

Tags: php, regex, config

I need to parse the configuration data of the following type, to be able to find and change the setting in a certain section (for example, parameter *adapter* in section *eth_ph_pure*):

```
[global]
db_ip = 127.0.0.1
db_port = 1215
control_port = 1233

[eth_ph_pure]
adapter_name = eth0
#adapter = 0
loging   = false
log_in   = false
log_out  = false
```

I use the [following regular expression](http://regex101.com/r/fQ6sV3/2) for achievement of this purpose:

```
/\[eth_ph_pure][^\[]*(?<!#)adapter\s*=\s*(.*?)\s/s
```

But if I put spaces after the *'#'* symbol,  it finds value despite commented-out line. I don't need to receive value of the commented-out parameter.

How do I fix a regular expression?

Comment: [`parse_ini_file()`](http://php.net/parse-ini-file) ?

Comment: Like @HAL9000 just said you should use http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

Comment: `(?<!#)adapter` means don't match the string `adapter` which was just after to `#`

Comment: @HAL9000, my comments begin with '#', instead of ';'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below regex,

```
/\[eth_ph_pure\].*?#\s*adapter\s*=\s*\S+(*SKIP)(*F)|\[eth_ph_pure\].*?\s*adapter\s*=\s*(\S+)/s
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fQ6sV3/6)

Comment: I don't need to receive value of the commented-out parameter

Comment: @ollazarev then for your input you need an empty string as output. Am i correct?

Comment: It don't work. I have problems when there are spaces after the '#' symbol in commented-out line.